# Sqlite The database file is locked database is locked

Tags: c, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I constantly write an error, the database is locked. I just can not understand why this is happening.
**db_login.cs**

```
private db_controller _dbctrl = new db_controller();
    public SqliteDataReader dataread;
    private string query;

//this two inputField, 
 public void LoginToGo()
    {
        login = _login.captionText.text;
        pass = _pass.text.ToString();
        query = "SELECT id from users where users = '" + login + "' AND pass = '" + pass + "'";
        try
        {
            dataread = _dbctrl.ExecuteReader(query);
            if(dataread.HasRows & dataread != null)
            {
                while (dataread.Read())
                {
                    VerifyAdmin();
                    _dbctrl.Disconnect();
                } 
            }
            else
            {
                errortxt.text = "Неверный логин или пароль, пожалуйста повторите!";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { errortxt.text = ex.ToString(); }
    }

 public void VerifyAdmin() //Who are you, admin or user
    {
        login = _login.captionText.text;


        query_access = "SELECT root from users where users = '" + login + "'";
        try
        {
            dataread = _dbctrl.ExecuteReader(query_access);
              while (dataread.Read())
               {
                if(dataread[0].ToString() == "0" || dataread[0].ToString() == null)
                {
                    MainMenu();

                }
                else
                    {
                    AdminMenu();

                }
               }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { errortxt.text = ex.ToString(); }
    }

    public void AdminMenu()
    {
        JOIN.SetActive(false);
        ADMIN.SetActive(true);
    }
    public void MainMenu()
    {
        JOIN.SetActive(false);
        MAIN.SetActive(true);
    }
```

**db_controller.cs**

```
public SqliteConnection con_db;
    public SqliteCommand cmd_db;
    public SqliteDataReader rdr_db;


public void connections()
    {

        try
        {

            if(Application.platform != RuntimePlatform.Android)
            {
                path = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/db.bytes"; // Путь для Windows
            }
            else
            {
                path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/db.bytes"; // Путь для Android
                if(!File.Exists(path))
                {

                     WWW load = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + "db.bytes");
                     while (!load.isDone) { }
                     File.WriteAllBytes(path, load.bytes);
                }
            }

        con_db = new SqliteConnection("URI=file:" + path);
        con_db.Open();
        if (con_db.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {

                debugText.text = path.ToString() + " - is connected";
                Debug.Log(path.ToString());

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            debugText.text = ex.ToString();
        }
    }

//Тут я создаю метод отключения
 public void Disconnect()
    {

        con_db.Close();
    }

 public SqliteDataReader ExecuteReader(string query)
    {
        connections();
        try
        {
            cmd_db = new SqliteCommand(query, con_db);
            rdr_db = cmd_db.ExecuteReader();
            return rdr_db;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { debugText.text = ex.ToString(); return null; }
    }

//Тут я записываю данные. Заодно решил проверить закрыто ли соединение.

 public void SetDB()
    {

        if (con_db.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            Debug.Log("open");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("close!");
        }
//The connection is closed. But I can not complete the request cmd_db.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connections();
        try
        {
            brand = AutoName.captionText.text;
            model = AutoModel.captionText.text;
            years = OldAuto.captionText.text;
            number = GosNumber.text.ToString();
            nusers = UserName.text.ToString();
            dbirthday = DBirthday.captionText.text;
            mbirthday = MBirthday.captionText.text;
            ybirthday = YBirthday.captionText.text;
            mobile = Mobile.text.ToString();
            cmd_db = new SqliteCommand("INSERT INTO clients(brand,model,years,number,nusers,dbirthday,mbirthday,ybirthday,mobile,groupmodel) values('" + brand + "', '" + model + "','" + years + "','" + number + "','" + nusers + "','" + dbirthday + "','" + mbirthday + "','" + ybirthday + "','" + mobile + "','" +groupmodel+ "')" , con_db);
            cmd_db.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Swears, says that the base is locked. And why? I just read the data and the connection was closed.

        }
        catch (Exception ex)  { debugText.text = ex.ToString(); }
        Disconnect();
    }
```

the documentation says:
This error code occurs when you try to do two incompatible things with the database at the same time from the same connection to the database.

But the connection with the base is closed.
Maybe I'm missing something, or not doing the right thing. I ask for help to clarify this issue.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any extra software that has the database opened ? such as sqlitebrowser for example

Comment: often its the vs ide that has it open..

Comment: and the plugin Firefox is considered?
But I do not work in it. And I use a portable program

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid. But you can see for yourself.
http://www.mediafire.com/file/t9zeek8299m9ieg/CarShower.7z/file